# convert a matrix to column vector rowwise

Tags: matlab, matrix

In Matlab by default convert a matrix to column vector is done column-wise.

Can we do this row-wise.

```
A = magic(3);
A =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2


column_vector = A(:);
column_vector =

 8
 3
 4
 1
 5
 9
 6
 7
 2
```

% This can be done rowwise indirectly by transpose or reshape

```
column_vector = reshape(A',1,numel(A))';
column_vector =

 8
 1
 6
 3
 5
 7
 4
 9
 2


trA = A';

column_vector = trA(:);
column_vector =

 8
 1
 6
 3
 5
 7
 4
 9
 2
```

Is there a direct way to do this row-wise like A(:)?

Thanks,
Gopi

Comment: ***1.*** `'` is not transpose. It is complex conjugate transpose. ***2.*** What's wrong with the transpose-reshape approach?

Comment: yes ' is complex conjugate. There is nothing wrong with transpose-reshape approach. I am just looking to find if there is a straight one-liner function to do this

Comment: It is already a one-liner with the transpose-reshape approach. (The use of `numel` can be avoided though.

Comment: @Gopi If you have the Comms Toolbox, there's also [`vec2mat`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html): `column_vector = vec2mat(A,1)`. But I would go with the transpose- reshape-transpose approach